# How to get the string to be run through the loop a second time with the adjusted string index?

Tags: c++, c++11

Trying to write code that will take an input string and "abbreviate" it. for example if aabb is given then the output should be bc. Basically if there's any double letters it goes up to the next letter in the alphabet so aa = b and so on. This works fine for the first run through but it won't loop through until completion. if the given string is aaaa the output should be c but instead the code outputs bb. how can I adjust my code to run the string an appropriate amount of times?

```
string abbreviate (string loc){

int loopCount;
sort(loc.begin(), loc.end());

for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < loc.length() ; i++){


    if(loc[i] == loc[i+1]) {
        if(loc[i] == 'a'){
            loc[i] = 'b';
            loc[i+1] = 0;

        }else if(loc[i] == 'b'){
            loc[i] ='c';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'c'){
            loc[i] ='d';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'd'){
            loc[i] = 'e';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'e'){
            loc[i] ='f';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'f'){
            loc[i] ='g';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'g'){
            loc[i] ='h';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'h'){
            loc[i] ='i';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'i'){
            loc[i] ='j';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'j'){
            loc[i] ='k';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'k'){
            loc[i] ='l';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'l'){
            loc[i] ='m';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'm'){
            loc[i] ='n';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'n'){
            loc[i] ='o';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'o'){
            loc[i] ='p';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'p'){
            loc[i] ='q';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'q'){
            loc[i] ='r';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'r'){
            loc[i] ='s';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 's'){
            loc[i] ='t';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 't'){
            loc[i] ='u';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'u'){
            loc[i] ='v';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'w'){
            loc[i] ='x';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'x'){
            loc[i] ='y';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }else if(loc[i] == 'y'){
            loc[i] ='z';
            loc[i+1]= 0;
        }


    }
}

return loc;
}
```

Comment: what should `zz` do? should `aaa` produce `ab` or `ba`?

Comment: I noticed that you sort the string to start, that means that even if I gave you the string `abab` you are going to process it and modify it as if it was the string `aabb`, is that really what you intend?

Comment: The quick answer is you setup a while(1) loop around the whole thing. Have a boolean that tracks if a change is made (anytime a substitution occurs, set it to true, reset to false at beginning of loop).  If you get to the end and that bool is still false (unchanged), break out.

Comment: That big `if` /`else if` ghetto could be replaced with a 26 element array. If you want to assume a character set with contiguous letters, you can replace it all with a bit of math (and maybe a single if).

Comment: BTW, setting the second character to 0 will NUL terminate your string.  Don't think that is what you want either.  You may need a memmove()

Comment: What does `loopCount` do?

Comment: You should probably also change your for loop to condition from `i < loc.length()` to `i < loc.length() - 1`. The string class treats `[]` in a special way when you reference a position that is equal to the length and returns you the null terminator and so this piece of code works without throwing an exception `if(loc[i] == loc[i+1])`.  If you were working with a vector or something else, you would have a range error.

Comment: @CoryKramer z is an exception. zz = zz.

Comment: @pstrjds Yes I do intend to sort it.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I will try that. I believe photometricstereo put that as the answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a nested loop with a variable checking if something has been changed in the last loop iteration. For example, your code would look similar to this:

```
// Pseudocode
bool changed = true; // This will keep track if previous loop has changed any values
while (changed) {
    changed = false; // Set to false at beginning of loop
    for (size_t i = 0; i < stringLength; ++i) {
        if (/*two same characters in a row*/) {
            // Change character to the next one in the alphabet
            changed = true; // This will indicate the outer loop to run again
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the program will only stop if all of the concurring characters have been changed.

There are a few other issues in your code such as indexing errors, here is an example how I implemented your functionality: https://wandbox.org/permlink/n0hk8SOpNEo6iZV7

Comment: I'm sure this would work but the only problem is that my program doesn't send the new letters to a new string array. so for example in string  test = bbb after it goes through my code I end up with test[0]= c test[1] = 0 and test[2] = b.  is there a way I can write it so that instead of just replacing that character with a 0 it will completely erase the character so the index numbers rearrange? @PhotometricStereo

Comment: I changed my code so that instead of `loc[i+1] = 0` It did `loc.erase(i+1, 1)` Then I added the while loop that you suggested and it worked perfectly! While not needed now I have to think about how to fix the if/if else ghetto that a user pointed out above. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I encourage you to debug this yourself, however you can open the wandbox link to see how I did it.